# Multiple Ajax calls / JQuery / JQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, mobile

I've got two divs, we'll all them id=one and id=two for ease.
There is an ajax call that determines either "one" or "two" should be shown. Both will not be shown.

div one = message
div two = input box

Step A) A generic ajax call populates the message as needed and makes the div visible.
 
Step B) I then use JQuery to determine if div one is visible. 
If so, make div two invisible. Else, make div two visible.

The problem is,  it works, but Step B isn't seeing the change in the html even though it happened...until the **second** event is fired (keypress or autocomplete).

I am wondering if it might be because JQuery Mobile has to first update the fields underneath.

The simplified code looks like this:
    
    $(document).ready(function() {

```
    $('input[name="foo"]').keyup(function() {  
        MakeAjaxRequest(ajax params);  //this updates div 1 and makes it visible 
        if ($('#one').is(':visible')){                
            $('#two').hide();   
        } else {   
            $('#two').show(); 
        }
    });
});
```

I've been able to hide and show other things in JQuery Mobile with no problem.

ps: I have also tried doing a .refresh() on div 1 after the ajax call.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax request is asynchronous, your visible check will be being done before the callback of your MakeAjaxRequest function has updated the html.

Comment: I found that jquery has an ajaxsuccess function that worked for me and replaced the ajax. Thanks!